# Free Groups and Actions on Trees

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, trees, free-groups, geometric-group-theory

Here is the proof of a theorem I am working through in Geometric Group Theory by Clara Loh:

[image]

The first paragraph shows that if $F$ is free, then it admits a free action on a (non-empty) tree. This paragraph gives me no trouble. On the other hand, the second paragraph, which proves that $F$ admitting a free action on a (non-empty) tree implies it is free, is giving trouble. First, why is $S$ a free generating set? Isn't that tantamount to assuming that $F$ is free, which is what we are trying to prove? Second, why does the left action of $F$ on $Cay(F,S)$ imply that $F$ is free?

Here is proposition 4.1.10:

> **Proposition 4.1.10 (Free actions on Cayley graphs)** Let $G$ be a group and let $S$ be a generating set of $G$. Then the left translation action on the Cayley graph $Cay(G,S)$ is free if and only if $S$ does not contain any elements of order $2$

Theorem 3.3.3 might be relevant, but I'm not sure...

> **Theorem 3.3.3 (Cayley trees and free groups)** Let $G$ be a group, let $S \subseteq G$ be a generating set satisfying $s \cdot t \neq e$ for all $s,t \in S$. If the Cayley graph $Cay(G,S)$ is a tree, then $S$ is a free generating set of $G$.

Comment: The first paragraph only describes why there is an action of $F$ on a tree. The second paragraph goes on to explain why this is a free action. Note that the proof starts by saying "part I". So the two paragraphs just prove one direction of the theorem. The proof of the other direction comes after in Section 4.2.2.

Comment: Beware that the action has to be free on the 1-skeleton, not only on the 0-skeleton (otherwise $Z/2Z$ has such an action).